# Does $ \sum_1^\infty {(-1)^n \over n \ \log_x(p_n)}$ converge for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does
$$ \sum_1^\infty {(-1)^n \over n \ \log_x(p_n)}$$
converge for all x, where $p_n$ is the nth prime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\frac{1}{n\log_x(p_n)} \geq 0$, and decreases monotonically to zero, your series converges by the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n \over n \,\log_x(p_n)}=\log(x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n \over n \, \log(p_n)}$$

Use the bounds of the prime numbers and the alternating series test ad the squeeze theorem.